# Get Parameters of JSON Object or a Map<String, String>

Tags: java, json, get, hashmap

how do I get the elements like "firstname", "lastname", etc. If they are in this format:

```
{     "count" : 2,

     "elements" : [

         {             "firstname" : "XXXXXXXXXX",             "lastname" : "A22"         },

         {             "firstname" : "YYYYYYYYYY",             "lastname" : "A23"         }     

]

}
```

And how do I get elements[0], and elements[1]?
This is because I want to validate the content in each parameter.

-Important-

My elements are coming form an API in Json Format, and I parse into Map<String, String> so I just need a solution to either a Json format or a Map<String, String> format.

I try using userDetails.get("elements")[1], and userDetails.get("elements").[SOMETHING] but anything worked, and I didnt get anything in the autocompletion...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON library such as [json-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String jsonData = "{\"count\":2,\"elements\":[{\"firstname\":\"XXXXXXXXXX\",\"lastname\":\"A22\"},{\"firstname\":\"YYYYYYYYYY\",\"lastname\":\"A23\"}]}";
    Object obj = parser.parse(jsonData);
    // A JSON object. Key value pairs are unordered. JSONObject supports java.util.Map interface.
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    // A JSON array. JSONObject supports java.util.List interface.
    JSONArray elements = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("elements");
    elements.forEach(e ->{
        JSONObject element = (JSONObject) e;
        System.out.println(element.get("lastname"));
    });
```